# How to stream and capture MP4 file using MPEG DASH?

Tags: nginx, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash, kaltura

I am learning MPEG-DASH for a week. For testing purpose , I used :
https://github.com/kaltura/nginx-vod-module -> MPEG-DASH server to stream MP4 video.

I have not found that , How to configure MP4 file path inside nginx.conf.

Can some one suggest me on it?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this:
https://www.instructables.com/Making-Your-Own-Simple-DASH-MPEG-Server-Windows-10/
https://www.bbsmax.com/A/RnJWw1koJq/

1. using ffmpeg convert files to different resolution ones
2. using MP4Dash to dash mp4 files
3. push mp4 dash files to nginx server
   the nginx config maybe like below:

   ```
    server {
        listen       ;
        server_name  www.testvideo.com;

        location / {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods “GET,HEAD;
            add_header Accept-Ranges "bytes";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
            add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers “Content-Lengrh,Content-Range,Date,Server,Transfer-Encoding,origin,range,x-goog-meta-foo1”;
            root    E:/video/fragment/output;

        }
    }
   ```
4. config node js

BR,